# Xbee wifi with iphone point-to-point connection

Tags: iphone, networking, connection, udp, wifi

I managed to send data from an iphone to an xbee wifi module using an infrastructure setup with the asyncudpsocket framework from github. (iphone->modem->xbee on helicopter) Had some serious delay problems with this so I thougt about creating an ad-hoc, point-to-point connection. Now with some fiddling the xbee module shows up on the iphone's hotspot list and can connect to it. But now what? Should it work with the same application as it did during the infrastructure setup (it doesn't at the moment) or there's something else I need to do first? Any help is appreciated.